# PPTP and L2TP VPN stop working on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, pptp, l2tp

I use VPN to access a server to work on.

The server runs in the university network, and I need to use a VPN from home to connect to the university network and access the server.

The problem is that I have moved out the city to spend holidays (so I'm using other network, provider etc), and in this network the VPN is not connecting anymore (at least using Linux), it just says "activation of the network failed" after some waiting.

I do have a dual boot, with Windows 11 the VPN connects as usual, so it's not a problem from my router/network but from some Ubuntu configuration.

The VPN is PPTP
IPV4: Automatic (DHCP)
IPV6: Automatic

Error: activation of the network failed

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

> *-network
> description: Wireless interface
> product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
> vendor: Intel Corporation
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
> logical name: wlp7s0
> version: 99
> serial: 5c:cd:5b:93:76:eb
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
> configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-56-generic firmware=29.4063824552.0
> 7265D-29.ucode ip=192.168.0.117 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
> wireless=IEEE 802.11
> resources: irq:138 memory:b3300000-b3301fff   *-network
> description: Ethernet interface
> product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
> vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
> logical name: enp8s0
> version: 10
> serial: 64:1c:67:c4:06:54
> capacity: 1Gbit/s
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd
> autonegotiation
> configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.049.02-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
> port=twisted pair
> resources: irq:126 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b3204000-b3204fff memory:b3200000-b3203fff

I have tried using cable connection, same error.

I have tried this tutorial: https://www.cyberithub.com/error-activation-of-network-connection-failed-on-linux/

results:

```
sudo nmcli connection up "VPN" --ask
```

> You need to authenticate to access the Virtual Private Network “VPN”.
> Password (vpn.secrets.password): 
> ••• Error: Connection activation failed:
> Unknown reason Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=80□□□□□□->3□□□□-4□□□□-8□□□-527□□□□□□□ + NM_DEVICE=wlp7s0'
> to get more details.

```
journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=80□□□□□□-3□□□□-4□□□□-84□□-52□□□□□□□□ + NM_DEVICE=wlp7s0
```

> jan 01 04:01:00 user NetworkManager[657]:   [1672556460.9554]
> device (wlp7s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake ->
> completed jan 01 04:01:00 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672556460.9554] device (wlp7s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5
> (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network
> "Wifi_name" jan 01 04:01:00 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672556460.9555] device (wlp7s0): state change: config -> ip-config
> (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') jan 01 04:01:00 user
> NetworkManager[657]:   [1672556460.9565] dhcp4 (wlp7s0):
> activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds) jan 01
> 04:01:03 user NetworkManager[657]:   [1672556463.0378] dhcp4
> (wlp7s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.117 jan 01
> 04:01:03 user NetworkManager[657]:   [1672556463.0423] device
> (wlp7s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none',
> sys-iface-state: 'managed') jan 01 04:01:03 user NetworkManager[657]:
>   [1672556463.0447] device (wlp7s0): state change: ip-check ->
> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') jan 01
> 04:01:03 user NetworkManager[657]:   [1672556463.0449] device
> (wlp7s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none',
> sys-iface-state: 'managed') jan 01 04:01:03 user NetworkManager[657]:
>   [1672556463.0469] device (wlp7s0): Activation: successful,
> device activated. jan 01 05:01:02 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672560062.9865] dhcp4 (wlp7s0): state changed new lease,
> address=192.168.0.117 jan 01 05:54:43 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672563283.9751] dhcp4 (wlp7s0): state changed new lease,
> address=192.168.0.117 jan 01 06:50:16 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672566616.9754] dhcp4 (wlp7s0): state changed new lease,
> address=192.168.0.117 jan 01 07:43:07 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672569787.9774] dhcp4 (wlp7s0): state changed new lease,
> address=192.168.0.117 jan 01 08:36:19 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672572979.9758] dhcp4 (wlp7s0): state changed new lease,
> address=192.168.0.117 jan 01 09:29:58 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672576198.9751] dhcp4 (wlp7s0): state changed new lease,
> address=192.168.0.117 jan 01 10:22:40 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672579360.9751] dhcp4 (wlp7s0): state changed new lease,
> address=192.168.0.117 jan 01 10:36:21 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672580181.1833]
> vpn[0x560c□□□□□□□□,80a□□□□□-36□□-4□□□-8□□□-52□□□□□□□□□,"VPN"]:
> starting pptp jan 01 10:36:21 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672580181.2288]
> vpn[0x560c□□□□□□□□,80a□□□□□-36□□-4□□□-8□□□-52□□□□□□□□□,"VPN"]:
> secrets: failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available
> for thi> jan 01 10:36:30 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672580190.9402]
> vpn[0x560c□□□□□□□□,80a□□□□□-36□□-4□□□-8□□□-52□□□□□□□□□,"VPN"]:
> starting pptp jan 01 10:37:06 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672580226.5451]
> vpn[0x560c□□□□□□□□,80a□□□□□-36□□-4□□□-8□□□-52□□□□□□□□□,"VPN"]: dbus:
> failure: connect-failed (1)

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

it says LCP Timeout sending Config-Requests

> Jan  1 11:02:15 user kernel: [79916.378096] Lockdown: systemd-logind:
> hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
>  Jan  1
> 11:02:16 user NetworkManager[657]:   [1672581736.7718]
> vpn[0x560c□□□□□□□□,80a□□□□□-36□□-4□□□-8□□□-52□□□□□□□□□,"VPN"]:
> starting pptp
>  Jan  1 11:02:16 user NetworkManager[657]: 
> [1672581736.7722] audit: op="connection-activate"
> uuid="80a□□□-36□□-4□□□-8□□□-52□□□□□□" name="VPN" pid=1758 uid=1000
> result="success"
>  Jan  1 11:02:16 user pppd[1138750]: Plugin
> /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.9/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
>  Jan  1 11:02:16
> user NetworkManager[1138750]: Plugin
> /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.9/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
>  Jan  1 11:02:16
> user pppd[1138750]: pppd 2.4.9 started by root, uid 0
>  Jan  1
> 11:02:16 user pppd[1138750]: Using interface ppp0
>  Jan  1 11:02:16
> user NetworkManager[1138750]: Using interface ppp0
>  Jan  1 11:02:16
> user NetworkManager[1138750]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
>  Jan  1
> 11:02:16 user pppd[1138750]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
>  Jan  1
> 11:02:16 user pptp[1138756]: nm-pptp-service-1138745
> log[main:pptp.c:353]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
> Jan  1 11:02:16 user NetworkManager[657]:   [1672581736.8685]
> manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device
> (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/12)
>  Jan  1 11:02:16 user
> systemd-udevd[1138755]: Using default interface naming scheme
> 'v249'.
>  Jan  1 11:02:16 user pptp[1138767]:
> nm-pptp-service-1138745 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control
> packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
>  Jan  1
> 11:02:16 user pptp[1138767]: nm-pptp-service-1138745
> log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:781]: Received Start Control Connection
> Reply
>  Jan  1 11:02:16 user pptp[1138767]: nm-pptp-service-1138745
> log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:815]: Client connection established.
> Jan  1 11:02:17 user pptp[1138767]: nm-pptp-service-1138745
> log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 7
> 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
>  Jan  1 11:02:17 user pptp[1138767]:
> nm-pptp-service-1138745 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:900]: Received
> Outgoing Call Reply.
>  Jan  1 11:02:17 user pptp[1138767]:
> nm-pptp-service-1138745 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:938]: Outgoing call
> established (call ID 50121, peer's call ID 60626).
>  Jan  1 11:02:47
> user pppd[1138750]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
>  Jan  1
> 11:02:47 user NetworkManager[1138750]: LCP: timeout sending
> Config-Requests
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user NetworkManager[1138750]:
> Connection terminated.
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user pppd[1138750]:
> Connection terminated.
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user charon: 13[KNL]
> interface ppp0 deleted
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user NetworkManager[657]:
>   [1672581767.8919]
> vpn[0x560c□□□□□□□□,80a□□□□□-36□□-4□□□-8□□□-52□□□□□□□□□,"VPN"]: dbus:
> failure: connect-failed (1)
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user
> gnome-shell[1758]: Removing a network device that was not added
> Jan  1 11:02:47 user pptp[1138756]: nm-pptp-service-1138745
> warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:226]: short read (-1): Input/output
> error
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user NetworkManager[1138750]: Terminating on
> signal 15
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user NetworkManager[1138750]: Modem
> hangup
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user NetworkManager[1138750]: Child process
> /sbin/pptp 150.162.0.66 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring
> nm-pptp-service-1138745 (pid 1138753) terminated with signal 15
> Jan  1 11:02:47 user pppd[1138750]: Terminating on signal 15
>  Jan
> 1 11:02:47 user pptp[1138756]: nm-pptp-service-1138745
> warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:238]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd
> log
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user pppd[1138750]: Modem hangup
>  Jan  1
> 11:02:47 user pptp[1138767]: nm-pptp-service-1138745
> log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:245]: Closing connection
> (unhandled)
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user pptp[1138767]:
> nm-pptp-service-1138745 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control
> packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user
> pptp[1138767]: nm-pptp-service-1138745
> log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:84]: Closing connection (call
> state)
>  Jan  1 11:02:47 user pppd[1138750]: Child process
> /sbin/pptp 150.162.0.66 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring
> nm-pptp-service-1138745 (pid 1138753) terminated with signal 15
> Jan  1 11:02:47 user pppd[1138750]: Exit.

---

My PPTP VPN is still not working, but I have a workaround with L2TP

***Upgrading xl2tpd 1.3.12 to 1.3.16 breaks VPN connection***

https://github.com/xelerance/xl2tpd/issues/230

1- Download: xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb
from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb.html

2- Go to the folder you have download the file and install the package with: `sudo dpkg -i xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb`
you should see >> **dpkg: warning: downgrading xl2tpd from 1.3.16-1ubuntu0.1 to 1.3.12-1.1**

3- Make sure the version is now 1.3.12 running `xl2tpd --version`
you should see >> **xl2tpd version: xl2tpd-1.3.12**

4- Reboot and try to connect your L2TP VPN

Comment: It's okay to include screenshots, but if you do so, it's also highly recommended to include the actual text, formatted in markdown code-blocks.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) for many reasons why.  Thanks!

Comment: I have replaced the images with text, thanks.
I have managed to have L2TP working, but PPTP shows the same error and still does not work.